# How to get multiple values selected from the drop down to views.py

Tags: python, django

Am using the following code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-left: 30px;">
            <select id="month" name="month" multiple>

                  <option value="01">January</option>
                  <option value="02">February</option>
                  <option value="03">March</option>
                  <option value="04">April</option>
                  <option value="05">May</option>
                  <option value="06">June</option>
                  <option value="07">July</option>
                  <option value="08">August</option>
                  <option value="09">September</option>
                  <option value="10">October</option>
                  <option value="11">November</option>
                  <option value="12">December</option>


            </select>
          </div>
```

**Views.py**

```
def internal(request):
   try:
       year = ''
       month = []
       year = request.GET.get('year')
       month = request.GET.get('month')
       print(month)
       response_list = []
   except Exception as e:
       print(str(e))
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_list))
```

I am selecting more than one value in the front-end but when I fetch it in views.py only one options is getting fetched. How do I fetch all the values selected from dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`getlist(key)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

Like this:

```
month = request.GET.getlist('month')
```

[`get(key)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) will get you only the last selected value:

> If the key has more than one value, it returns the last value.

Comment: If you use `getlist()` you will get more than one value if you also selected more than one. Your current solution with `get()` will get you only the last selected value.

Comment: I wound want more than one value. how can I get that ?

Comment: But am still getting a single value.

Comment: Are you creating your request with jQuery? Try `getlist('month[]')` if so.

Comment: This is my javascript code:  `function internal() 
{
  
  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  var month= document.getElementById('month').value;
    
  console.log(month);
  $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': '/myBlog/internal/',
       data: {
            'year':year,
            'month':month,}`